# Plot cumulative value for different series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have run a short simulation and want to plot the outcomes of each simulation in terms of the "running sum" over parameter k. For reference, I want to end up with a plot that looks similar to the ones in this article:

https://www.pinnacle.com/en/betting-articles/Betting-Strategy/betting-bankroll-management/VDM2GY6UX3B552BG

The following is the code for the simulation:

```
## Simulating returns over k bets.
odds <- 1.5
k <- 100
return <- odds - 1
edge <- 0.04
pw <- 1/(odds/(1-edge))
pl <- 1-pw

nsims <- 10000
set.seed(42)
sims <- replicate(nsims, {
  x <- sample(c(-1,return), k, TRUE, prob=c(pl, pw))
})

rownames(sims) <- c(1:k)
colnames(sims) <- c(1:nsims)
```

If I wasn't being clear in the description let me know.

Comment: Do you want to plot the cumulative value of K per simulation ? Please specify exactly what is the expected output

Comment: hi @julien, the expected output is one like in the article I linked in the question (you can see the first graph if you scroll down a bit on the article).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is how you can achieve the plot of the cumulative value over bets (I set `nsims <- 10` so that the plot is readable).

First I generate the data :

```
## Simulating returns over k bets.
odds <- 1.5
k <- 100
return <- odds - 1
edge <- 0.04
pw <- 1/(odds/(1-edge))
pl <- 1-pw

nsims <- 10
set.seed(42)
sims <- replicate(nsims, {
  x <- sample(c(-1,return), k, TRUE, prob=c(pl, pw))
})

rownames(sims) <- c(1:k)
colnames(sims) <- c(1:nsims)
```

Then I create a dataframe containing the results of the n simulations (10 here) :

```
df <- as.data.frame(sims)
```

What we want to plot is the cumulative sum, not the result at a specific bet so we iterate through the columns (i.e. the simulations) to have that value :

```
for (i in colnames(df)){
  df[[i]] <- cumsum(df[[i]])
}
df <- mutate(df, bets = rownames(df))


output <- melt(df, id.vars = "bets", variable.name = 'simulation')
```

Now we can plot our data :

```
ggplot(output, aes(bets,value,group=simulation)) + geom_line(aes(colour = simulation))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Julien, I appreciate it!